# Laravel new controller method in xampp object not found error

Tags: php, laravel-5, xampp

I created a Laravel 5 project and new controller `Pagecontroller` with `about` method also I configure route file as `Route::get('about','PageController@about');`

> Controller

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PageController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

        public function about(){
            return "Kanishka";
        }
```

Im using appache on xampp. when i call this method `http://localhost/laravel/public/about/` it goes to `http://localhost/about` and page displays

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL
>   manually please check your spelling and try again.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>   Error 404

but when I chage root route as `Route::get('/','PageController@about');` it is working.

Comment: Could you post the route file that generates this error?

Comment: Nothing wrong with Laravel here, you've got some funky XAMPP stuff going on.

Comment: Please post the code in your `route.php`, and did you create a view for the about page? should be something like `app/views/about.blade.php`

Comment: Laravel should be configured such that "public" is the root of what's facing the web.

Comment: Try removing the latest `/`. LIke this: `http://localhost/laravel/public/about`

Answer (score 1):

Do like this

```
Route::get('about', [ 'as' => 'page.about', 'uses' => 'PageController@about' ]);
```

And write functions with the `get` keyword. (`getAbout`)

[Examples of Laravel routes](https://github.com/CodepadME/laravel-tricks/blob/master/app/routes.php)

Comment: yeh.. it also correct.. but in this case it happens coz  XAMPP